# WHERE clause with the LIKE operator error

Tags: where-clause, sql-like

I want to use WHERE ...LIKE... statement to search on the two parent tables, namely: **t_persons** and **t_incidents**.

The INNER JOIN works fine but when I include a WHERE ... LIKE ... statement, no records are returned.

Also, when I input a keyword in the form to search with e.g. FamilyName LIKE 'mulenga', and IncidentCountryID LIKE '243', I get this error printed out:

```
SELECT ip.PersonID, ip.IncidentID, p.ImagePath, p.FamilyName, p.FirstName, p.OtherNames, p.Gender, p.CountryID, i.IncidentDate, i.IncidentCountryID, i.AgencyID, i.StatusID, i.KeywordID FROM t_incidents i INNER JOIN t_incident_persons ip ON ip.IncidentID = i.IncidentID INNER JOIN t_persons p ON ip.PersonID = p.PersonID WHERE p.FamilyName LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND p.FirstName LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND p.OtherNames LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND p.Gender LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND i.IncidentDate LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND i.KeywordID LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND i.IncidentCountryID LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND i.StatusID LIKE '% AND `FamilyName` LIKE '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND ip.PersonID>0 ORDER BY PersonID DESC LIMIT 0,24You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%mulenga%' AND `IncidentCountryID` LIKE '%243%'%' AND p.FirstName LIKE '% AND ' at line 12
```

My SELECT statement is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT ip.PersonID, ip.IncidentID, p.ImagePath, p.FamilyName, p.FirstName,
  p.OtherNames, p.Gender, p.CountryID, i.IncidentDate, i.IncidentCountryID,
  i.AgencyID, i.StatusID, i.KeywordID

FROM t_incidents i 
INNER JOIN
  t_incident_persons ip ON ip.IncidentID = i.IncidentID 
INNER JOIN
  t_persons p ON ip.PersonID = p.PersonID    

  WHERE 
    p.FamilyName LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    p.FirstName LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    p.OtherNames LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    p.Gender LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    i.IncidentDate LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    i.KeywordID LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    i.IncidentCountryID LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    i.StatusID LIKE '%" . $likes . "%' AND
    ip.PersonID>0

ORDER BY PersonID DESC $pages->limit";
```

My tables are set up like below (**t_incident_persons** being a junction table):

```
t_persons
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| PersonID  | FamilyName| FirstName| CountryID|
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|         1 | Bupe      | Joseph   | 243      |
|         2 | Kansi     | Brown    | 243      |
|         3 | Luma      | Henry    | 243      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+

t_incidents
+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+--------+
| IncidentID   | IncidentCountryID |IncidentDate |OffenceKeywordID|AgencyID|StatusID|
+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+--------+
| 1            | 243               |12/03/2003   |1               |6       |2       |   
| 2            | 243               |15/05/2004   |1               |6       |2       |
| 3            | 243               |16/12/2007   |3               |6       |3       |
+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+--------+--------+

t_incident_persons
+-----------+----------+
| IncidentID| PersonID |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 1        |
| 1         | 2        |
| 1         | 3        |
+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND` between the likes?

Comment: If you put `FamilyName LIKE 'mulenga', and IncidentCountryID LIKE '243',`into the $likes it's no wonder that you get incorrect syntax. Notice what the error message actually tells you about the syntax. It shows you what's incorrect.

Comment: Resolved. Thank you all for your help.